# MvvmLightToolkit: Is the DispatcherHelper.Initialize() method's execution needed?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone, mvvm-light

The `Mvvm Light Toolkit` include the `DispatcherHelper` that is a very useful tool. It allows to synchronize the main `UI Thread` from a background thread in a very simple way. For instance `DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI()`:

```
//In any moment before...
DispatcherHelper.Initialize();

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
    o => 
    {
        //Do something

        DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(()=>StatusTextBlock.Text = "Done");
    }
);
```

Before using the `DispatcherHelper` I usually use the `MainThread`'s `SynchronizationContext` for submitting any change from a non main thread to the view.

My question is: why is it necessary the `DispatcherHelper.Initialize` method execution before using the class? Can it be called on the static constructor for the first time? For instance:

```
public class DispatcherHelper
{
    private static void Initialize()
    {
         //...
    }
    static DispatcherHelper(){
        Initialize();
    }
    //...
}
```

I think in this way it is not needed

Comment: So, I believe it's because the `Dispatcher` is often not available until after app initialization. The `DispatcherHelper` cannot know when this happens from the library itself, so it relies upon the user to let it know. With your method, the user could theoretically attempt to use the `DispatcherHelper` before it has access to the `Dispatcher`, so could throw an exception or just not call the requested method. `tl;dr` it's that way to protect the developer from creating a situation the `DispatcherHelper` can't handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After making a research, I think I found a good reason:

This reason could be that `DispatcherHelper.Initialize();` method should be executed in the main thread, and if it is done automatically using the static constructor, there exists a possibility that the static constructor executes on another background thread.